# Enumerating Assigned ShortCuts in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I frequently create new macros in Excel.  When assigning the macro to a shortcut key combo it is necessary to try many times before getting one that is not already in use.  I want to determine all of the "used" shortcuts either from VBA or any other method available.

Comment: See http://www.xcelfiles.com/GetShortCutKeys.html and http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/01/05/macro-shortcut-keys/ for some interesting information.

Comment: Hi @Remou... That first link should really be an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (not super convenient but it works)

1. Export your code module as a .BAS file using File > Export
2. Open the .BAS file with a text editor
3. You'll see lines like this:

> Attribute f.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "q\n14"

That means that this function is assigned to Ctrl+q.

Answer (score 0):

We created an add-in that may solve this problem.  http://datamules.com/course/shortcuts has a short tutorial on shortcuts, but the "Shortcuts Extras" link has an add-in for Excel 2007+ that let's you type in a key and see what the key-sequence is assigned to.

Hope that helps!